# Why is the password populating on the url?

Tags: javascript

I have developed some forms using Eleventy and I never had any issues with the credentials appending themselves to URL, but now I have made a new password authentication form and this one is appending the password to the url and I am unclear as to why.

This is the Eleventy form:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return `
    <form class="rds-form">
     <div>
      <input
        type="password"
        id="input_password"
        name="Password"
        aria-required="true"
        class="form-control to-switch"
        maxlength="32"
        data-required-message="A password is required to login. Please add it now"
      / >
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
       <button
         type="submit"
         class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit-btn"
         id="custom-password"
        >
        Login
        </button> 
      </div>
    </form>
  `
}
```

the logic for it:

```
document.querySelector('.rds-form').addEventListener('submit', function () {
 alert('form submitted!');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the API I am working with from a third party vendor does an AJAX call, so I had to add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default browser behavior like so:

```
document.querySelector('.rds-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 alert('form submitted!');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The `form` default method is `GET` so set the `method` attribute to `POST`.

```
<form class="rds-form" method="post">
```

Comment: Yep! https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp. method get is Default. Appends the form-data to the URL in name/value pairs: URL?name=value&name=value

Comment: @Daniel, I thought about that, but when I added method of post it did not work, I will try it again.

Comment: @Daniel you might need to cancel the submission to handle it with javascript

Comment: @DanielA.White, in fact, when I tried that, I got the error `Cannot POST /` with that long error of `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy Directive...`

Comment: you need to say what url for the `action`

Comment: @DanielA.White,  specified url of `action="#"` and I am still getting the `Cannot POST /` with the following error in console `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy Directive...`

Comment: @Daniel these are separate questions - you should keep a single question focused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222084/discussion-between-daniel-and-daniel-a-white).